# How to send a "string array" as HTTP post data from Python?

Tags: python, json, http, post, python-requests

I'm using Python to interface to a web service which receives http post messages. For one particular service, the documentation reads:

```
Parameters:

Name               Type           Value
meteringPointIds   String array   List of metering point ids

HTTP verb: POST
```

I only have one metering point id, so I'm using this construction:

```
postData = {'meteringPointIds': meteringPointId}
r = requests.post( url + path, headers=headers, json=postData)
```

The variable `meteringPointId` contains a string with the metering point id.

> #20013: No meteringpoints in request conforms to valid meteringpoint format.

Let's say the metering point id is 1234. I've tried

```
postData = {'meteringPointIds': 1234}
postData = {'meteringPointIds': [1234]}
postData = {'meteringPointIds': ['1234']}
postData = {'meteringPointIds': '[1234]'}
postData = {'meteringPointIds': ["1234"]}
postData = {'meteringPointIds': "[1234]"}
```

But no matter what I do, I always get the above error. What am I missing?

Web service documentation:

[Customer and Third party API for Datahub Eloverblik Technical description](https://energinet.dk/-/media/D3186E9D405348EDAC25EF50D3D9CDB0.pdf)

[API - Data Description](https://energinet.dk/-/media/733793361EC040E8A8AE1534B1D52A7B.pdf)

Comment: it totally depends on endpoint you are using.

Comment: Can you post the link to the web service's documentation that you mentioned?

Comment: I've added links to the two documents provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this JSON:

```py
postData = {
    "meteringPoints": {
        "meteringPoint": [
            "1234"
        ]
    }
}
```

or, maybe

```py
postData = {
    "meteringPointIds": {
        "meteringPoints": {
            "meteringPoint": [
                "1234"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing - your first suggestion worked! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try a string with comma-separated values. I don't think you need a comma for just one value.

```
postData = {'meteringPointIds': "1234"}
```